# NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point: SqlException: The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type geography

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

`var point=new Point(24.616305177995866, 93.75792101605397) { SRID = 4326 };`
When I am saving the point into the database with this coordinate database giving an error
While It is working with rest of all coordinate only not working for 24.616305177995866, 93.75792101605397

I check the database it also supporting the SRID 4326 [Please see the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8FPm.png)

Comment: what is "the rest of the coordinates"? Can you give an example where it is working? I think 93degree north/south simply is not a valid longitude.

Comment: I think that @MakePeaceGreatAgain has the right of it - this appears to be a domain issue. You know your data - are the coordinates provided as (lat, long) or (long, lat)? If the latter, 93 is indeed out of range as a latitude (which can be ±90).

Comment: Could you share the code used to save it into the database, and also more details about the error it is giving?